# Can propositions involving second-order predicate logic be proved from ZFC and NK, which are first-order predicate logic?

Tags: lo.logic

According to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108415/what-is-the-relationship-between-zfc-and-first-order-logic ,
ZFC is first-order logic.

Also, accodring to wikipedia about second-order logic(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Expressive_power) we need second-order logic to express the proposition that "whenever there is a set of real numbers that is not empty and bounded above, there is an upper bound on that set”.

So, how can we write propositions expressed in such second-order predicate logic based on ZFC? Or are propositions such as the existence of an upper bound independent of ZFC? Or we use second order version ZFC?(in spite that second-order logic does not admit a complete proof theory?)

I understand that the continuum hypothesis is independent of ZFC, but it is hard to imagine that such an ordinary proposition as this is independent of ZFC.

Comment: This is a good question, but better for math.stackexchange than mathoverflow. Briefly, there is simply no problem with proving results about second-order logic using (a theory in) first-order logic; second-order logic is a mathematical object itself, after all.